# How do I exclude more than 50 variables from an SQL query?

Tags: sql, graph, graphite

I am trying to generate metrics from a database query but need to exclude several results from the graph. When I try to do nested exclude statements it reaches a point where it won't generate the graph anymore so I suspect I am reaching an upper limit of the number of functions one can nest.

> highestCurrent(exclude(exclude(exclude(exclude(exclude(exclude(exclude(exclude(exclude(exclude(exclude(DB.INC.GROUP.*,'NOC'),'DEPT-H'),'DEPT-B'),'TX-NOC'),'Core-NOC'),'DEPT-N'),'RAN-NOC'),'IP-NOC'),'NOC-A'),'NOC-P'),'NOC-M'),5

Anyone know of a better way to do this ?

graphite version is 0.9.15-1 on ubuntu 16.04

Regards,

Eric